# How to extract last digit which has hyphen or not without indexing

Tags: python

```
import re
address = """1183 Pelham Wood Dr, Rock Hill, SC 297-32"""
zip_code = re.findall(r'(\d+)(?!.*\d)', address)
print(zip_code)
```

Required output: 297-32

I need to get the full number which has hyphen or not.. without using indexing.. Is there any solution

Comment: why the number `1183` should not be captured? You wrote "full number which has hyphen or not"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$` to anchor the end of the string in a lookahead pattern to find the last digits directly:

```
re.search(r'\d+(?:-\d+)?(?=\D*$)', address).group()
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/ExcellentAllEngineering

Answer (score 0):

A simple start would extract the number-pattern "digits including hyphen" from the end: `[0-9-]*$`

Works for all of those:

```
1183 Pelham Wood Dr, Rock Hill, SC 297-32
1183 Pelham Wood Dr, Rock Hill, SC 297
1183 Pelham Wood Dr, Rock Hill, SC -
1183 Pelham Wood Dr, Rock Hill, SC 1-
```

See [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/OJd4oX/1).

To capture US-postal codes [ZIP+4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_Code#ZIP+4) you might even find better solutions here on Stackoverflow, e.g. using tags [`[zipcode][regex]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zipcode+regex).

Answer (score 0):

I interpret "extract last digit" as meaning the last sequence of digits that *may* be interspersed with hyphen. In which case:

```
import re
address = """1183 Pelham Wood Dr, Rock Hill, SC 297-32"""
if g := re.findall(r'\d+-*\d*', address):
    print(g[-1])
```

**Output:**

```
297-32
```